# validates_confirmation_of :password

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have this code, that works, but I'm not really sure how?

It validates passwords but how does it do this?

I know what an attr_reader and accessor are but don't really understand how datamapper knows to compare :password with :password_confirmation? What magic is datamapper performing?

Here is my user model:

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-postgres-adapter'
require 'bcrypt'

class User

  include BCrypt
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :username, String
  property :email, String
  property :password_digest, Text

  validates_confirmation_of :password

  attr_reader :password
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation

  def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
  end

end
```

Here is my controller post:

```
post '/sign-up' do
    new_user = User.create(:username => params[:username], :email => params[:email], :password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation])
    session[:user_id] = new_user.id
    redirect '/welcome'
  end
```

Comment: The questions you are asking are probably too broad in scope. When I started learning Ruby I made the mistake of actually learning Rails first, which makes heavy use of DSL (Domain Specific Languages) such as the `property` and `validates` macros in your example. I'd highly recommend learning Ruby first, not a specific library like DataMapper.

Comment: Hey Kris sorry I wasn't clear, I am actually learning Ruby first, I start Rails in a few weeks. I tagged Rails in the hope that it would broaden my outreach because they use datamapper in a similar way.

Comment: When I refereed to Rails, I also mean all libraries, such as DataMapper, Sinatra etc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dm-validations/DataMapper/Validations/ValidatesConfirmation) for `validates_confirmation_of`

The "magic" happening is only that data-mapper will search for a field with the same name of the one you passed in the `validates_confirmation_of` (in this case `:password`) with `_confirmation` in the end and verify if they are equal.

For example `validates_confirmation_of :email` will make datamapper look for an attribute `email_confirmation` and compare if it's equal to `:email`.

**attr_reader and attr_accessor**

The `attr_reader` and `attr_acessor` are just 'shortcuts' to define methods and instance variables.

- `attr_reader`: creates a method that gets the attribute
- `attr_writer`: creates a method that sets the attribute
- `attr_accessor`: creates both

For example:

```
class Person

   attr_reader :name
   attr_accessor :gender

end
```

Is the same thing of:

```
class Person

  def name
    @name
  end

  def gender=(gender)
    @gender = gender
  end

  def gender
    @gender
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks so much lcguida! That really helped make things clear and click!

Comment: Glad I could help